# How to debug: Firefox can not lookup DNS

Tags: dns, firefox

Suddenly Firefox-ESR and Iceweasel can not lookup DNS but `/etc/hosts` works fine. Other programs does also work fine: `konqueror`, `wget` and `curl`.

I have gone through http://mzl.la/1xKrMnN **Firefox can't load websites but other browsers can**, no firewalls prevent Firefox from DNS, IPv6 disabled, no proxy and no DNS prefetching.

```
$ egrep "network.dns.dis|proxy" ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js 
user_pref("network.dns.disableIPv6", true);
user_pref("network.dns.disablePrefetch", true);
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 0);
```

I have tried `reboot`, `reinstall`, `purge & install`. Login as a new defined user does not work either. Then:

```
mkdir debug ; cd debug
strace -o f -ff firefox http://example.org/
grep -rn example.org f*
```

and to have something to compare with

```
strace -o k -ff konqueror http://example.org/
grep -rn example.org k*
```

I have gone through the files but have not found any *smoking gun* yet. Where to go from now? Reinstall the computer?

Comment: did you try this?
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-and-diagnose-firefox-problems

Comment: Yes. And I just checked the plugins: They were all deactivated or "ask to activate". I also did a `rm -rf ~/.mozzila/`.

Answer (score 0):

Your size of `/etc/hosts` is way too big:

```
$ ls -l /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5128 Oct  2 12:20 /etc/hosts
```

There is a bug here. If the file size is 1562 bytes Firefox can read it. If it is 1588 bytes or more Firefox can not use DNS.

Conclusion: Either don't use Firefox or cut down `/etc/hosts` to **1562 bytes**.

This bug applies to Firefox version 45.4.0.